# Closed subgroups of totally disconnected Polish amenable groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, topological-groups, amenability

Let $G$ be a totally disconnected Polish topological group (e.g., a closed subgroup of the homeomorphism group of the Cantor set). If $G$ is amenable, is every closed subgroup of $G$ also amenable?

Notes: This is apparently not true if we remove the "totally disconnected" requirement. It is true if we require $G$ to be locally compact.

Comment: The extremely amenable totally disconnected Polish group $\mathrm{Aut}(\mathbf{Q},\le)$ contains a free subgroup of rank 2 as (closed) discrete subgroup. (Fix a left-invariant total ordering on $F_2$, and let $F_2$ act on itself $X=F_2\times\mathbf{Q}$ with lexicographic order. This action is free and $X$ is isomorphic to $\mathbf{Q}$ as chain. So this realizes $F_2$ as discrete subgroup of $\mathrm{Aut}(\mathbf{Q},\le)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "$F_2$ act on itself $X=F_2\times Q$"

Comment: oops: $F_2$ acts on itself, and trivially on $\mathbf{Q}$, and consider the product action on $X=F_2\times\mathbf{Q}$.

Comment: Thanks again! Is it easy to see that this subgroup is discrete and closed?

Comment: Discrete implies closed. Yes any subgroup of Sym(N) acting freely is clearly discrete.